# Issue with Copy Constructor with Binary Trees

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having an issue with my copy constructor for my Binary Search Tree (BST).
Especially on the first pass through of the copy constructor. I have tested my `insert300` functions and they work great. When I through in the copy constructor, I get a segmentation fault  in my private `insert300` function. Some how `8` isn't getting assign to the top of the tree. The exact location of the segmentation fault is the private `insert300` where it tests if the `element == root->element`. So I don't know what I am missing to fix this. Can some one lead me into the right direction.

Also sorry about the naming convention on `root`. I will change that to parent when I get done with all my functions. Also if there is confusion on the data types passed in. Look at my header file!

Header:

```
#ifndef _OLSOND5_H
#define _OLSOND5_H

typedef float Element300;
struct TreeNode300;
typedef TreeNode300 * TreePtr300;
struct TreeNode300
{
    Element300 element;
    TreePtr300 left;
    TreePtr300 right;
};

class BST300
{
    public:
        BST300();
        BST300(const BST300 &);
        ~BST300();
        void insert300(const Element300);
        void remove300( const Element300);
        TreePtr300 search300(const Element300) const;
        void preView300() const;
        void inView300() const;
        void postView300() const;
    private:
        TreePtr300 theTree;
        void copy300(const TreePtr300);
        void destroy300(TreePtr300 &);
        void removeNode300(TreePtr300 &);
        void findMaxNode300(TreePtr300 &, TreePtr300 &);
        void insert300 (const Element300, TreePtr300 &);
        void remove300(const Element300, TreePtr300 &);
        TreePtr300 search300(const Element300, const TreePtr300) const;
        void preView300(const TreePtr300) const;
        void inView300( const TreePtr300) const;
        void postView300(const TreePtr300) const;

};




#endif
```

Copy Constructor Function(The copy constructor calls this functions):

```
 void BST300::copy300(const TreePtr300 oldTree)
{
    if(oldTree != NULL)
    {
        insert300(oldTree->element);
        copy300(oldTree->left);
        copy300(oldTree->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Private `insert300` function:

```
   void BST300::insert300(const Element300 element,TreePtr300 & root)
{
    TreePtr300 newNode = new(std::nothrow) TreeNode300;

    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Node was not created!" << endl;
    }
    else if(root == NULL)
    {
        newNode->element = element;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right =NULL;
        root = newNode;
    }
    else if(element == root->element)
    {
        cerr << "The number " << element << " is a duplicate. Not Added!" << endl;
    }
    else if(element < root->element)
    {
        insert300(element, root->left);
    }
    else
    {
        insert300(element, root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Driver Program:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "olsond5.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BST300 myBinarySearch;

    myBinarySearch.insert300(8.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(4.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(12.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(2.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(6.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(10.0);
    myBinarySearch.insert300(14.0);

    BST300 myBinarySearch2(myBinarySearch);

    cout << "INVIEW" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    myBinarySearch2.inView300();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code for your copy constructor. If you want to get help quickly, post all of your code somewhere, e.g. github with a script that compiles it and runs the test driver.

Comment: My Copy constructor calls my insert. Ill post my whole copy constructor function but I tried to point out where it gets segfaulted at. @SashaPachev

Comment: Do you initialize theTree with NULL in BST300's copy constructor?

Comment: @MichaelNastenko Thank you! So much. That got me out of the seg fault!

Comment: You are welcome. And make yourself used to initialize all pointer to NULL in constructors :-)